# Creating a Basis with constraints

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to find a basis for $R^4$ space in the form $(a, b, c, d)$ where $d=a+b$ and $c=a-b$.

I can answer $(a)$ and $(c)$ but part $(b)$ is giving me a bit of trouble https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOSXO.png

I'm not really sure where to start. The answer sheet lists $(a + b + (a+b) + (a-b))$ = $a(1, 0, 1, 1) + b(0, 1, 1, -1)$.

From this I can gather that they've substituted the variables for $c=(a+b)$ and $d=(a-b)$ into the equation but I can't for the life of me see where the $a(1, 0, 1, 1) + b(0, 1, 1, -1)$ comes from.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every vector in that subspace can be written as
$$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\a-b\\a+b\end{bmatrix}
= a \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
+ b \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

A vector of the form $(a,b,c,d)$ with $d=a+b$ and $c=a-b$ can be rewritten as $(a,b,a-b,a+b)$ and further broken up into $$(a,0,a,a)+(0,b,-b,b)=a(1,0,1,1)+b(0,1,-1,1) $$

Can you see the basis now? The point is that we separate the $a$ and $b$ "stuff" into different vectors to get a basis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ravi, I follow up to the 1st two columns using your method - I took this approach myself - I'm just not following the last two columns for a and b. It appears to me that we're substituting in a known value of 1 for 'a' and 'b' in columns 3 and 4, I'm not sure how if that's a correct interpretation of your method and if so how we come to know that a and b are 1.